# Can anyone tell, what is OBJECT TYPE in collection?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Am new to oracle. I searched in google for OBJECT TYPE in collection, but cant find any simple and detailed information.
   Help me to know about OBJECT TYPE with some example. And practically where it is used?

Comment: You might get better search results if you specify Oracle and PLSQL as well. This might be a good place to sart: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/10_objs.htm

Answer (score 2):

The best source of information is the "Object-Relational Developer's Guide" - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/

There are SQL types (also called "schema types") and PL/SQL types.

SQL types are created by the CREATE TYPE statement. PL/SQL types are declared in PL/SQL code. PL/SQL knows about SQL types, but PL/SQL types cannot be used in SQL statements.

SQL types are either **objects** or collections of objects.

PL/SQL types are either **records** or collections of records, or collections of objects.

SQL objects are so named because they can hold both attributes and methods, just like objects in languages such as Java. The methods are usually written in PL/SQL.

There are many different uses of SQL objects. I don't know how to make a complete list. At the very least, if you have a collection in PL/SQL and you want to use it in a SQL statement, the collection must be based on a SQL collection type, which is always based on a SQL object type.

Best regards, Stew Ashton

Comment: Thanks @Stew Ashton